# Adding an environment variable to an ec2 instance with boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, boto

Pretty simple question, but I can't find anyone addressing it, or really any mention of the problem. Basically I'm looking to add a small amount of information to a remote ec2 box by associating an environment variable with the box when I'm spinning it up.

I've seen some mention of the concept of `tags`, but I'm looking for something that I can naively check and access from within the instance, and it's not clear if `tags` provide that functionality.

Ideally the interface to add these environment variables would also not be accessible by any external party after the instance has been instantiated.

I realize I could achieve a similar effect by setting up a secure database, but that seems overly involved for just trying to add a couple pieces of metadata to the instance.

Not looking for a handout, but any link to some documentation on this would be much appreciated. I'm currently using `boto` (code below), so something that fits into the `boto` framework would be ideal, but if I have to drop down to amazon's REST api it wouldn't be the end of the world.

```
def create_instances(connection, type, number, **kwargs):
    kwargs.update({
        'min_count': number,
        'max_count': number
    })
    return connection.run_instances(**kwargs).instances  # maybe if kwargs had an environment variable?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to pass information to an Amazon EC2 instance, but not all of them would necessarily meet your requirement for it not being accessible after launch.

**User Data**

When launching an Amazon EC2 instance, User Data can be specified. The contents of the User Data is accessible from within the instance by accessing the URL:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/
```

Your code on the instance could query this URL (which is intercepted by the hypervisor, and viewable only from the instance itself) to access the information.

Another use for User Data is that it can [execute as a script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts). The script could set an environment variable that your code can then access.

However, the User Data can be viewed via the EC2 Management Console or via a `DescribeInstanceAttribute` call, so this might not meet your requirement for security.

**Tags**

Another option is to use Tags. These are Name-Value pairs associated with an EC2 instance (or other objects within AWS). Tags can be retrieved via a call to 'DescribeTags', but boto has some shortcuts to access them.

Tags are a great way to associate information with an instance, and tags can also be used to identify specific instances (eg by environment, project, owner...).

However, the values stored in Tags are viewable in the EC2 Management Console and via API calls.

**Other options**

- Retrieving values from a **database** (but then you have the problem of how to authenticate against the database)
- Storing data on an **AMI** (but this doesn't make it easy to modify values on a per-instance basis)
- Storing data in **Amazon S3** and using an IAM role assigned to the instance to provide credentials to retrieve the data from S3
- Retrieving data from a code repository (but, again, security concerns)

Comment: Thanks so much John! I wasn't aware of the user-data option, but that seems like the best approach here. There'll be some hacking, but I think there's enough there for me to work with. Thanks so much!

Comment: Related to the environmental variable setting from the user_data script, does this approach always work? When I use it to set the PYTHONPATH variable as described in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845062/import-error-loading-module-using-bash-script-on-ec2-instance-aws/62845502#62845502 the python specific case still fails. I invite you to take a look as I'm still trying to get to the bottom of that issue.

Comment: @seeiespi Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.